# $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{\sin x}^{\cos x} \cosh t^2 dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Given that $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{\sin x}^{\cos x} \cosh t^2 dt$$

How could I evaluate this ? Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $F'(t) = f(t)$, then
$$\int_a^b f(t)\, dt = F(b)-F(a)$$
If we make the bounds $g(x)$ and $h(x)$, then we have
$$\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(t) \,dt = F(h(x)) - F(g(x))$$
Taking the $x$ derivative of both sides gives us
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)} f(t) \, dt = h'(x)f(h(x))-g'(x)f(g(x))$$
Now you can just plug into this formula.

Comment: Can you give me the answer? I'm not sure if my solution is correct. Thanks

Comment: It's $-\sin(x)\cosh(\cos^2(x))-\cos(x)\cosh(\sin^2(x))$

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just by first principles...

$$ I =\int \cosh t^2 dt = \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}(t)+\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}(t) + C$$

Then evaluated at $t =\cos x$ and $ t=\sin x$, (i.e., $I\bigg\rvert_{\sin x}^{\cos x}$) we get

$$\left[ \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}(\cos (x))+\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}(\cos (x))\right] - \left[ \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}(\sin (x))+\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}(\sin (x))\right]$$

$$-\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}(\sin (x))+\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}(\cos (x))-\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}(\sin (x))+\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}(\cos (x)) $$

Next, take the derivitive w.r.t. $x$ and we get

$$ -\frac{1}{2} \sin (x) e^{\cos ^2(x)}-\frac{1}{2} \sin (x) e^{-\cos ^2(x)}-\frac{1}{2} e^{\sin ^2(x)} \cos (x)-\frac{1}{2} e^{-\sin ^2(x)} \cos (x)$$